# Fetching data from webpage to desktop app

Tags: java, html, swing, web-scraping, netbeans-7

I am working on a desktop application.  How can we retrieve data from a website and place that format exactly on desktop application?  Means I want to represent webpage *(**not full page**, some block)* from a website and use it in my desktop application.

I am using Netbeans IDE.

Comment: *"(Not full page some block)"* Many sites do not want desktop applications (other than browsers) to embed their pages.  If they want to offer 'part of the data' that appears on the web page (e.g. football results, train timetables or exchange rates) they will typically offer an API to directly obtain that information.  What site are you wanting information from?

Comment: thnaks andrew, you got my point - sorry to say my client not given from which website they want to get the data - but they said do with some samples.

Comment: *"sorry to say my client not given from which website they want to get the data - but they said do with some samples"*  Sorry to say that on that basis, I am not willing to help you or your client. This smacks too much of 'data theft' & as the owner of a number of domains, that is not something I approve of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look to the [How to use html in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) or [simple browser via Swing](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JEditorPane.html)

Comment: thanks but i dont want to type the url everytime it will be in code and that app should run with windows

Comment: Yep, you can put your html as hardcode, or url, and show html like described in first example, or download html from url, parse it and agin show as in first example.